Inverse and Determinant of Matrix $Axx^TA+cA$
Fix $c \in \mathbb{R}$, a symmetric (if needed, positive definite) $n \times n$ real matrix $A$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. I need help computing the determinant and inverse of the $n \times n$ matrix:
\begin{equation*}
Axx^TA +cA
\end{equation*}
Preferably, the answer should be in terms of $\det(A)$, $tr(A)$, $A^{-1}$, $c$, and $x$. If this is not doable, in terms of $A$ (or any decomposition of it), $c$, and $x$ is also acceptable. If for general $c$ the question is too difficult, the special case $c = -x^TAx$ is of particular interest.
It feels quite uncomfortable that $Axx^TA \neq (x^TAx)A$. The $ij$th entry of $(x^TAx)A$ is $\sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=1}^n x_ax_bA_{ab}A_{ij}$. The $ij$th entry of $Axx^TA$ is $\sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=1}^n x_ax_bA_{ia}A_{jb}$. And it does not seem to have any reasonable way to simplify their difference! It is also not so clear how techniques like diagonalization can help solving it .

For $c=-x^TAx$, $x\ne 0$, the matrix $M=Axx^TA+cA$ is not invertible (determinant is zero) as $Mx=0$.

Why is $Mx=0 $?

Hint: Assuming $A$ is psd, $Axx^{\top}A + cA = A^{1/2} (c\cdot I + yy^{\top}) A^{1/2}$, where $y = A^{1/2}x$. Thus, $(Axx^{\top}A + cA)^{-1} = A^{-1/2} (c\cdot I + yy^{\top})^{-1} A^{-1/2}$. You can use the Sherman Morisson formula for the central term. However, as pointed out above the matrix is not invertible for $c = -x^{\top}Ax$, which is something you will also obtain after applying the Sherman Morisson formula.

By calculation:
$$
Mx=(Axx^TA+cA)x=Ax\cdot (-c)+cAx=-cAx+cAx=0
$$
as the scalar $c$ commutes with $Ax$.
